# Recenter map that crosses international dateline with ggplot and geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf, rnaturalearth

Consider the map of Europe below. Parts of Russia are on the other side of the map. How might I "recenter" the map so that there is less empty space? I guess I need to somehow move the polygons on the left to the right?

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", continent = "europe") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Something similar is described here, though I can't replicate their results yet: https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2019/04/30/zooming-in-on-maps-with-sf-and-ggplot2/

Answer (score 1):

you can give it a new coordinate system to transform it to where your area of interest is centered on your map using the coord_sf() function.

for my example I grabbed a somewhat arbitrary coordinate system defined as well known text (WKT) from: https://projectionwizard.org/

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)


domainCRS<- paste('PROJCS["ProjWiz_Custom_Lambert_Azimuthal"',
            'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984"',
        'DATUM["D_WGS_1984"',
        'SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]]',
        'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0]',
        'UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]',
        'PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"]',
        'PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0]',
        'PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0]',
        'PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",109.69]',
        'PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",12.55]',
        'UNIT["Meter",1.0]]',
        sep = ',')

map<-ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", continent = "europe")
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = map)+
  coord_sf(crs = domainCRS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There still seems to be an annoying polygon on the left though. I guess there is trivial way to move it to the right?

Comment: That eastern polygon shows up in your original map. It is a territory of France. If you limit your plot to `geom_sf(data = map[map$sovereignt == "France",])` you will see that it appears in that map.

Comment: Try this for a more conventional rectangular projection: 
'domainCRS<- paste('PROJCS["ProjWiz_Custom_Plate_Carree"',
    'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984"',
    'DATUM["D_WGS_1984"',
    ' SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]]',
    ' PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0]',
    ' UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]',
     'PROJECTION["Plate_Carree"]',
     'PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0]',
     'PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0]',
     'PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",105]',
     'UNIT["Meter",1.0]]',
      sep = ",")'

Comment: is there a way for a more user friendly way of doing this? What if I want to change only the 'PARAMETER["Central_Meridian"]'?